# Get greatest and greater objects from Generic List

Tags: .net, vb.net, generic-list

I have a list of `System.Version` objects,

I need to get the greatest version in the list and the versions greater than the specified one

```
Dim versions As New List(Of Version)
versions = LoadVersions()

' Get the greatest version object
Dim greatestVersion = versions.Greatest() '???

' Get version objects greater than the specified one
Dim ver = New Version("2.0.1.0")
Dim greaterVersions As List(Of Version) = version.GreaterThan(ver) '???
```

What would be a good way to do it?

Comment: yes but I'm looking for a way where I don't have to compare the Version object properties one by one to determine if the object is greater or not

Comment: My solution is posted below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I got to solve it, later I improved it as @Konrad suggested:

```
'Greatest version
Dim maxver = versions.Max(Of Version)(Function(ver As Version) ver)

'Greater versions
Dim currentVersion As New Version("2.0.1.0")
Dim geaterVers = versions.Where(Function(ver As Version) ver > currentVersion)
```

Comment: Your question didn’t deserve a downvote in my opinion but this answer is misleading: the other answer *does* work, and this one is unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Thanks @KonradRudolph you're right because of some issues in my environment I ended with this.
this may be useful for somebody else with similar environment issues

Answer (score 5):

Greatest version:

```
Dim greatestVersion = versions.Max()
```

Greater than selected version:

```
Dim greaterVersions = versions.Where(Function (x) x > ver)
```

Have a read through the [MSDN LINQ reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx).

Comment: `versions.Max()` is not accepted by the compiler, instead I need to use something like:

    versions.Max (Of )()

Comment: @armadillo.mx In that case you made a mistake somewhere. [Just using `Max` definitely works](http://ideone.com/Xz1O0j).

Comment: I've verified it also works, my environment was forcing me to use a different implementation (changing the syntax)

Comment: Even though I initially used my posted solution this is a simpler and clean way to do it